# db.fsyncLock() without permission in MongoDB (auth enabled)

Tags: mongodb, admin, fsync

i have added auth to my MongoDB instance. I created a user with the following command

```
db.createUser(
 { user: "cocodrile", pwd: "amazonas",
   roles: [
       { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"},
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "admin"},         
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "brasil_database"}, 
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "usa_database"} ,
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "argentina_database"},
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "test"}] })
```

I want to perform a **db.fsyncLock()** and it says:

```
db.fsyncLock()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { fsync: 1.0, lock: true }",
    "code" : 13
}
```

What i am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I want the user to be able to perform all possible operation in all databases :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the [hostManager](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#hostManager) built-in role, which has permissions to monitor and manage servers and perform some cluster-as-a-whole actions like fsync.